# How do I use ArrayAdapter to display a list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to display a list view in my application. Each row should contain a text and an image. I have used ArrayAdapter to display this but how to insert an image after the text.
Here is the code:

```
String lvr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cg_listview1);
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.alerts , lvr));
```

Here alerts is my layout which contains only a textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have control over how the layout of items look in a list view, you should make your own custom implementation of [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> A ListAdapter that manages a ListView
>   backed by an array of arbitrary
>   objects. (...) To use something other
>   than TextViews for the array display,
>   for instance, ImageViews, or to have
>   some of data besides toString()
>   results fill the views, override
>   getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to
>   return the type of view you want.

If you just google for [custom arrayadapter example](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+arrayadapter+example), you should find enough examples showing you how to implement this. Two such examples are:

- http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
- http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html

Good luck :)

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm on a mobile atm, so for simplicity I just copied an answer I had made to a similar question earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom adapter to achieve this.

```
public class ResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Result> results;

    public ResultAdapter(Context context, List<Result> results) {
        this.context = context;
        this.results = results;
    }    

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.results.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.results.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    }
}
```

Create a Result class for storing the text and the image. In the getView method create your View either programmatically or by loading it from an XML layout using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Answer (score 1):

Code complete with text view changes. The ArrayList is generic but you must use ArrayList constuctors for the add, insert and remove to work.

```
public class ListViewLearn extends Activity {

    public Button btnAddData;
    public ListView listShow;
    public listRayAdapter adapter;
    public ArrayList<Integer> tmpStrRay;
    public Resources mainRes;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlistlayout);

        tmpStrRay = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        tmpStrRay.add(1);
        tmpStrRay.add(2);
        tmpStrRay.add(3);
        mainRes= getApplicationContext().getResources();
        adapter = new listRayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listitem, tmpStrRay);

        btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddData);

        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(clickit);
        listShow= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listShow);
        listShow.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    final OnClickListener clickit = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int xx=4; xx<=50; xx++){ 
                adapter.add(new Integer(xx));
            }
        }};

    class listRayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>
    {
        private ArrayList<Integer> items;
        Bitmap tmpImg;

        public listRayAdapter(Context context, int textVwId, ArrayList<Integer> txtRay)
        {
            super(context,textVwId,txtRay);
            this.items = txtRay;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View newv= convertView;
            if (newv == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                newv = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            }
            if ((position%2)==0){
                tmpImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainRes, R.drawable.even);
            }else{
                tmpImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainRes, R.drawable.odd);
            }

            ImageView img = (ImageView) newv.findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageBitmap(tmpImg);
            TextView tt= (TextView) newv.findViewById(R.id.listedItem);
            Integer tmpInt = new Integer(items.get(position));
            tt.setText(tmpInt.toString());
            return newv;
        }

    }
}
```