# How to use this two ArrayAdapter constructor

Tags: java, android

When I read the API doc, I found 2 weird constructor in ArrayAdapter class:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId)

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
```

There is no List or Array to insert into this 2 public constructor (the rest has), then what are the purpose to have these 2 constructor? How to use them?

Comment: Did you see? [ArrayAdapter Help?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497510/arrayadapter-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two constructors are for initialization of ArrayAdapter if you donnot have any Array to display at the time of object creation. Once you create/receive your array you can use

> `public void addAll (Collection<? extends T> collection)`

to set an array to be displayed.

Comment: I thought we must inject the items when we create the object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use methods getItemViewType(int position) and getViewTypeCount() in your subclass of ArrayAdapter and List or Array of items should be a populated class field.